# How do I display an index change in ngFor (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, immutability, ngfor

I have a function called removePopUp. When I send an index sometimes I want to change whats inside that index in the array. Lets say I have an array of [0,1,2]. when I run removePopUp(1) that should return [0,2]
there should be no 3rd element but the 3rd index would slide to the second element removing that element. The issue is its not displaying this activity in angularJs when I'm using a ngFor to display a child component.

messages.component.ts

```
...
userPopUpsArray : BookFaceMessage[] = []
...
removePopUp(index){
    index = Number(index)
  let usersLength = this.userPopUpsArray.length
if (usersLength === 3){
  if (index === 1){
    let thrid_index = this.userPopUpsArray[2]
    this.userPopUpsArray[1] = thrid_index
  }
  else if(index === 0){
    let second_index = this.userPopUpsArray[1]
    let thrid_index = this.userPopUpsArray[2]
    this.userPopUpsArray[0] = second_index
    this.userPopUpsArray[1] = thrid_index
    this.userPopUpsArray.pop()

  }
  else{
    console.log(index)

    this.userPopUpsArray.pop()
  console.log(this.userPopUpsArray)
  }
}
else if (usersLength === 2){
  
  if(index === 0){
    this.userPopUpsArray[0] = this.userPopUpsArray[1]
    this.userPopUpsArray.pop()

  }
  else{
    console.log(index)

    this.userPopUpsArray.pop()
  console.log(this.userPopUpsArray)
  }
}
else{
  this.userPopUpsArray.pop()
}
getPopUp(){
  return this.userPopUpsArray
}
}
```

messages.component.html

```
...
 <div *ngFor="let userPopUpData of userPopUpsArray; let i = index;trackBy: getPopUp">
      <app-message-popup [userPopUpsArray]=userPopUpsArray [userPopUpData]=userPopUpData [removePopUp]=removePopUp [index]=i></app-message-popup>
...
```

```
</div>
```

Comment: First of all I would suggest to use just array.splice for removing the element - like this ```this.userPopUpsArray.splice(index,1)``` - this will remove the element on given index.  Regarding updating the view - which change detection strategy are you using?

Comment: You can also try to remove trackBy from your template as it does not give you any benefit in this form and may cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the `n-th` element of an array you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like this:

```
  removePopUp(index) {
    index = Number(index);

    // check if provided index is number
    if (isNaN(index)) {
      return;
    }

    // check if provided index is within array length
    if (index < 0 || this.userPopUpsArray.length <= index) {
      return;
    }

    this.userPopUpsArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Note: it is a good idea to check if provided index is number, and also if its value is within array length. Keep in mind providing negative value to `splice` will start looking from the end of the array so both checks are necessary.